# Ubuntu 14.04 Slow/unstable wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, internet

I have a lenovo Y-50 gaming laptop and after first boot I installed Ubuntu and avoided Windows 8 overall, anyways my internet is really slow and unstable even though the router is in the next room. Sometimes it even drops the connection overall and won't be able to see it and I am forced to turn off networking and then back on to see my wifi.

In games such as Dota 2: One moment my ping is 33m/s and then suddenly it spikes to 1000 and it has nothing to do with the amount of players on screen or "creeps". It's seriously annoying and I have no clue what to do as nothing else on the net really helped me.

Is it possible that I have a bad wifi card or is it something damaged or even some problem with drivers, please help me thanks!

Comment: What is the brand and model of your WiFi card? Which driver are you using?

Comment: Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 I am not sure what drivers I am using though.

Comment: What does `lsmod | grep wifi` return?

Comment: iwlwifi               169932  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              484040  4 wl,iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm

Comment: Then you're using the recommended driver, so it's definitely not that.

Comment: I can confirm, I have the same issue with the y50. I've even moved the laptop into the same room. Every other device is fine, just the laptop can't seem to work. Ping's easily go above several full seconds.

Comment: By the way, it works *great* on Windows 8, so it's not a hardware problem